# Difference between "つもりです" and "予定です"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I recently learned about both of them meaning "I intend/plan to..." but I don't know the difference between the two. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you understand the difference between an intention and a plan?

つもり is just your intention.  You don't necessarily have a plan.  Stating an intention doesn't mean you need to go through with it.

よてい is a plan.  You've made a commitment to do something, with just yourself, with someone else, either way.  Not following through on a plan suggests you're perhaps not someone who can be counted on.

On a scale of definiteness, it seems to me that

> 行こうと思っている

is the least definite;

> 行くつもりだ

sounds a bit more definite;

> 行く予定だ

sounds definite.